# What would be the best way to present a 2 item choice on mobile?

Tags: mobile, app

Let's say I'm trying to accomplish a task on a mobile app, in order to do so I need to choose one out of 2 options, for example, confirm via e-mail or text message.

Each choice leads the user to a different "path"

What's the best interface solution to present this choice to the user?

Comment: Why not just use 2 buttons?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what happens on selection of that element.

---

**1.** **If it is a link** to a new view/site, simply using two different buttons is usually clear:

[image]

This is an online shop giving the user the possibility to either log in into their account or to create a new one. You can see that the buttons are styled differently for primary and secondary actions.

---

**2. If it is a "toggle"** that adjusts what is currently shown on the screen, you can use something like iOS' ["segmented controls"](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/controls/segmented-controls/):

[image]

Here you can see how choosing one option immediately affects the content shown on screen.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to use the buttons with the required functions. Note that the buttons can be of different design and color. So you can make a brighter button and use it more often. It will draw attention to your goal.

Answer (score 0):

[image: toggle example] 
 
I would use something like this. Not necessaraly with this animation, but big enough so it can be toggled; left one option, right other.